# How do aysnchronous non-blocking IO clients work?

Tags: c#, java, asynchronous, async-await

I'm intrigued to know how clients, such as Java's AsyncHttp client or C#'s Async Web Request features work. Basically, how does the low-level code work to ensure that a thread is never just waiting for the result of an IO operation.

My guess is machine interrupts. But I have no clue how they work in high-level languages like C# or Java.

Comment: do you ask how io waits implemented in low level ?

Comment: I'm asking what these async libraries use that makes them non-blocking. I don't know if it is IO waits.

Comment: as far as I know, an async activity is performed with the help of an extra thread that is responsible for applying a given policy to the pipeline of tasks that is running on another thread. You basically send a task to the pipeline and you get notified when it's ready, that's it basically, you pay an extra in terms of CPU power wasted for this "policy thread" but you get an async behaviour on the other hand. That's what I remember from the first presentation of C# 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be any number of things. Most OS's today have non-blocking IO calls, it could switch to using those instead of the blocking IO calls. Lower level than that, it would depend on the device. Almost all devices do raise interrupts that get handled by an interrupt handler, but how the OS translates that into a non-blocking IO and how the completion works differs from OS and async implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way they work is through some OS API that sets a response to an interrupt to a generic handler, that generic handler is called, it spins up a new thread and the handler you provided is called. 

Here is more info on the Async Web Requests dealing with C#.
[Making Asynchronous Requests .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409(v=vs.100).aspx)